# How to make correct PathFinding for large size entity in cryengine?

Tags: path-finding, game-ai, cryengine

I have been confused by the pathfinding problem for a few days, it seems that the space between generated path and forbidden area are constant. I am really dry, and did not find anything relating to my question on official documentation.

I have tried to modify "pathfindProperties.xml", there is no difference when switching different "Type"
Scale up the radius of collider

is there anybody can give me a help? I really appreciate it!

{A screenshot of my question: http://www.crydev.net/download/file.php?id=86461}

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the problem, I found a solution:

To use the Multi-layer navigation mesh, rather than the default navigation system. And define a proper volume for actor via "NavigationType" property.